# How to copy text to / from clipboard in Go?

Tags: python, command-line, go, clipboard

In my Go language command line application, I need the ability to copy certain snippets of text to the system clipboard using Go. Basically something like [PyperClip](http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/), but for Go.

I'm looking for a platform agnostic solution! Any help would be great :)

Comment: I'm afraid there's no platform-agnostic solution, wrapped as neatly as in Java's standard library. You could use several platform-specific tools, such as `xsel` under X, `pbcopy` / `pbaste` under OSX, and `pclip.exe` under Windows.

Comment: There's no such thing as a platform agnostic clipboard. You could write something that would work on most major platforms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One project (just for Windows and Mac) seems approaching what you want: [`atotto/clipboard`](https://github.com/atotto/clipboard).

> Provide copying and pasting to the Clipboard for Go.

```
func ReadAll() (string, error)
func WriteAll(text string) error
```

Linux support is in this [clipboard_linux.go](https://github.com/atotto/clipboard/blob/master/clipboard_linux.go) class: a simple wrapper to `xsel --output/input --clipboard` system command.

---

Another approach: try and take advantage of third-party libraries, like [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/):

> a free, Open Source, multi-platform library for opening a window, creating an OpenGL context and managing input

Its Go wrapper [`glfw3`](https://github.com/go-gl/glfw3) does provide a [`clipboard.go`](https://github.com/go-gl/glfw3/blob/master/clipboard.go) file, with supposedly multi-platform methods.

```
func (w *Window) SetClipboardString(str string)
func (w *Window) GetClipboardString() (string, error)
```

But that would be in the context of GLFW windows, not any shell window of course.